# What SSIS variable/ paramter to use to capture looping server name?

Tags: ssis, parameter

I am a newbie to SSIS.

**BACKGROUND:-** We are trying to make Database Inventory of about 100 SQL Instances. First task is to check SQL connectivity for all servers and capture the failed connections. Although the package runs fine by using SELECT @@servername to capture SQLInstanceName, but there is below challenge.

**CHALLENGE:-** Using @@servername is not helpful in our case because many servers have their alternate DNS names in AD. Due to this, select @@servername returns the different name than that of hostname. Due to this, the final Inventory shows that DNS_Name, whereas the source server list has HOSTNAME. Hence @@servername creates a mismatch and not helpful for us.

**REQUIREMENT**:- Somehow capture the exact looping SQLInstanceName from the source server list instead of using @@servername. So, that we can have exactly the same name as in source list.

[image]

**Dynanmic Connection:** "Data Source="+ @[User::Srv_Conn]  +";Initial Catalog=master; Provider=SQLNCLI11; Integrated Security=SSPI; Connect Timeout=0; Auto Translate=False"

[image]

[image]

```
public void Main()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Dts.Variables["User::Srv_Conn"].Value.ToString() + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

        //MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::Srv_Conn"].Value.ToString());

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string SQLLoop;
            SQLLoop = Dts.Variables["User::SQLBeingLooped"].Value.ToString();
            Dts.Variables["User::SQLCommand"].Value = "SELECT" + SQLLoop + ",name from sys.databases where name not in ('master','model','tempdb','msdb','distribution','Autodeskreplication','AdminDB')";

            conn.Close();

            Dts.Variables["User::CFlag"].Value = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::CFlag"].Value = false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I know that it is all basics of C# and variables....I should learn these first. I am currently doing this on half knowledge. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you looping over all servers, or over all server's SQL Server instances? If you're looking for obtain SQL Server instance name, you can use the global variable [`@@servicename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servicename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), or the [`SERVERPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) built-in function and pass the `InstanceName` as parameter.